# how do i out put from AD or txt

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to run this programme against a a list of remote pc/servers either by AD out TXT and display them in either csv or html if any one can offer some help or advise I would be greatly appreciative.

My only limitation is all my machines run powershell v2 only

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | 
 Format-Table –AutoSize
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to take the output of that command and put it in a file?  PowerShell has a lot of tools to do this.  However, you need to remove the `Format-Table` command first.

See, `Format-Table` is all about making your command output look really good in a PowerShell window, so it's got a lot of hard returns and columns and things defined in it which make sense to the console, but look like garbage when you export it.

For data like this, I think Comma Separated Value is probably the way to go.

```
Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\* | 
    Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate | 
        Export-CSV -NoTypeInfo -Path \\server\share\$($env:ComputerName)_Programs.csv
```

This example will export a CSV, omitting the import-helper info PowerShell normally adds, using the `-NoTypeInformation` switch.  I figured it'd be useful to know the name of the computer which made the file, so that's just what it will do.  Edit `-Path` to point to a server with a share and away you go.  You'll end up with files like this:

- ComputerA_Programs.Csv
- ComputerB_Programs.Csv
- ComputerC_Programs.Csv

Comment: Brilliant thank you very much, still new to PS so getting the commands  in the right order is still confusing me (which isn't hard)

Comment: Sure, happy to help.  If this post was helpful to you, remember to mark as answer and vote up :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to pull from all Ad computers

```
ForEach ($COMPUTER in (Get-ADComputer -Filter *  | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name)) 
{if(!(Test-Connection -Cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
{write-host "cannot reach $computer" -f red}

else{Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*  | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
Export-CSV -NoTypeInfo -Path "\\server\share$\$Computer_Programs.csv" -NoTypeInformation}}
```

for if you have list of computers in text

```
Foreach ($computer in ($computers= Get-Content "c:\Computers.txt"   ))
{if(!(Test-Connection -cn $computer -BufferSize 16 -Count 1 -ea 0 -quiet))
{write-host "cannot reach $computer" -f red}

else{

 Get-ItemProperty HKLM:\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\*  | Select-Object DisplayName, DisplayVersion, Publisher, InstallDate |
    Export-CSV -NoTypeInfo -Path "\\server\share$\$Computer_Programs.csv" -NoTypeInformation

}}
```